# Coloring only specific Angular Material inputs

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have the following css styles defined in my component css file:

```
::ng-deep .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-selected,
.mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-state-done,
.mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-state-edit {
  background-color: red !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
  color: white !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-focused .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
  color: white !important;
}

::ng-deep
  .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-invalid.mat-form-field-invalid
  .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
  color: red !important;
  opacity: 0.8 !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-input-element {
  caret-color: red !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-invalid .mat-input-element,
.mat-warn .mat-input-element {
  caret-color: red !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-label {
  color: white !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
  color: white !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-label {
  color: red !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-select-value-text {
  color: white !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-select-arrow {
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

It works well, but all matinputs (also e.g. matselects) in the component are colored, I would like to only color specific matinputs. Even in other components loaded afterwards, the matinputs also picks up these color changes.

What is the way to control this for specific elements?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by going from css to scss and put a ".custom-mat" around the css and in the template added a div with the class surrounding the mat fields I wanted the styles to effect.